# Put content of access database into two listboxs

Tags: c#, database

Hi I have a database with two tables: 1.) Country (Table name: 2.) Website 
Every country has 1 or more websites.

I am trying to make a C# WindowsForm Application where I want the User first to select a country from the first listbox1 and then all the Websites will in the second listbox2 based on the database.. I somehow can't display all the countries in the first textbox using a select statement: the code is the following

```
try
{ 
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT CountryName FROM Countries ";
    //whenever you want to get some data from the database
    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(reader);
    }
    //OleDbDataReader reader   = command.ExecuteReader();
    connection.Close();
}
catch(Exception l)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:" + l);
}
```

This code doesn't show the items in the listbox.

Can someone please advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to get your data from the reader and convert it to an object before you put it in the listbox. You can get the value for each column by `reader["columnname"]`. Dont forget that you also need to convert each value to its proper type, you will probably find all types of conversion you need in `System.Convert`.

With your scenario in mind you should be able to do

```
using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(reader["CountryName"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the OleDbDataReader as a listbox item instead of using it to read the data, here is an example of how to use it :

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT CountryName FROM Countries ";
        //whenever you want to get some data from the database
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.NextResult())
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception l)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:" + l);
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```